# webpack - merge objects instead of overwriting them

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have to .ts projects in which I am using webpack to create a single .js file.

Like so:

```
Dev.Xrm.PM.js
Dev.Xrm.HR.js
```

I would like to call functions from both "PM" and "HR" on the same page.

```
Dev.Xrm.PM.Foo()
Dev.Xrm.HR.Bar()
```

In both projects/js-Files I am working with the namespace (modules) "Dev.Xrm".

When I am using both .js files on the same page, either "PM" or "HR" is available depending on which script is registered the last.
I think this is because how webpack is currently initiating "Dev" and "Xrm". The objects are getting overriden, but not extended. Also these last lines of the .js files indicate that:

```
/******/    // startup
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    // This entry module is referenced by other modules so it can't be inlined
/******/    var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__("./WebResources/code/index.ts");
/******/    window.Dev = __webpack_exports__;
/******/    
/******/ })()
;
```

Can I configure webpack so that in the resulting .js the objects are extended instead of being overwritten?

Changed the order of the script registrations. Expected the last one to win. Expectation was met.

Comment: "in which I am using webpack to create a single .js" VS "When I am using both .js files" - errrrr, do you have a single file or two (or more) files? And: Do you use webpack to generate 2 "library" files (one for `Dev.PM` and one for `Dev.HR`) and another "business logic" file (that uses `Dev.PM`/`Dev.HR`)? If so, why don't you use it like it's meant to be used and create a single entry point in which you use your libraries? The basic idea of a bundler is to create a single JS file that contains library code _as well as_ business code.